# How to Render conditionally

Tags: django, django-forms

The Model:

```
class Human(models.Model):
  UNIQUE = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  father = models.ForeignKey('Human', related_name = "fathers_children", null=True, blank=True)
  mother = models.ForeignKey('Human', related_name = "mothers_children", null=True, blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % name


class Person(Human):
  email = models.EmailField()
```

And now, I'm trying to make ModelForm:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('UNIQUE','name','email')
```

Till this - works perfect.

And now I want to add two fields: father and mother

If Person already has father (and/or mother) - just show name. If not - show input field (or both fields), where user has to type UNIQUE.

**UPDATED**

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('UNIQUE','name','email')
    widgets = {
      'father' :forms.TextInput(),
      'mother' :forms.TextInput(),
    }
```

This solution changed Select into TextInput, which is very good step. But now I see id of father/mother not name (which was seen in Select).

===================== WHAT IS EXPECTED ==================================
a small piece of graphics:

Case 1: Person has no parents

```
UNIQUE: [AAA]
name:   [John Smith    ]
email:  [john@smith.com]
father: [              ]
mother: [              ]
```

Case 2: Person has father

```
UNIQUE: [BBB]
name:   [Kate Late     ]
email:  [              ] 
father: Mike Tyson
mother: [              ]
```

Case 3: Person has both parents

```
UNIQUE: [CCC           ]
name:   [Jude Amazing  ]
email:  [jude@aol.com  ]
father: James Bond
mother: Alice Spring
```

Case 4: in Person [AAA] (case 1) user types mother: [BBB]

```
UNIQUE: [AAA           ]
name:   [John Smith    ]
email:  [john@smith.com]
father: [              ]
mother: Kate Late
```

(I hope that you can see the difference between [Kate Late] and Kate Late (without [])

Comment: To clarify: you want fields that already exist on the instance to no longer be editable?

Comment: Not exactly. This is easy to do with self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True or self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['disable'] = True. I need convert ChoiceField into TextField, but TextField contains id not value of Option

Comment: What do you mean by 'value of Option'? I'm not sure if I can understand this question, but it would be useful if you implement the method `__str__` (or `__unicode__`) on your models. After that look what appears in the TextField. As I said, I'm not sure what you are really after, this is just a guess.

Comment: The Select widget shows name of Person, defined in __unicode__. But TextField shows id (or pk), not name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step to heaven:

I remove father and mother from form, overwrite **init** and add two additional fields: father_input and mother_input

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.pk:             
      if instance.father is not None:
        self.fields['father_input'].initial = self.instance.father
        self.fields['father_input'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True

      if instance.mother is not None:
        self.fields['mother_input'].initial = self.instance.mother
        self.fields['mother_input'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True

  father_input = forms.CharField(required = False)
  mother_input = forms.CharField(required = False)

  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('UNIQUE','name','email')
```

So, now 1/2 of question is solved - when mother/father is defined - it shows name of father in non editable field.

Now it's time to serve the entering UNIQUE:

Fields father/mother input can contain any text - it isn't served by server now. So I have to add

```
def clean_mother_input():
  data = self.cleaned_data['mother_input']
  if data == '':
    return data # do nothing
  try:
    mother = Person.objects.get(UNIQUE=data)
    logger.debug("found!")
    self.cleaned_data['mother'] = mother
    return data
  except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise forms.ValidationError("UNIQUE not found")
```

(the same for father)

But I have also add back father and mother to Class meta, because without it, setting self.cleaned_data['mother'] does nothing.

```
  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('UNIQUE', 'name','email','father','mother')
    widgets = {
      'father': forms.HiddenInput(),
      'mother': forms.HiddenInput(),
    }
```

It works good, but would be perfect to remove hiddeninputs - showing father_id in source of html is not good. But for now, I have no idea how to send data to model without hiddeninput